# Saving a Spark dataframe with around 2k columns to Hive is extremely slow

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

Hi I have this code here:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(jobName)
conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)

val df = hiveContext.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
      .load(inputDir)

df.registerTempTable("df")

hiveContext.sql("SET hive.exec.compress.output=true")
hiveContext.sql("SET parquet.compression=SNAPPY")

// this is fast
df.take(1)

// this is way too slow
hiveContext.sql("CREATE TABLE myTable AS SELECT * FROM df")
```

It reads data from compressed avro files and store it in a Hive table. The load is fast and operations like count() or take() work as expected. However, the insert into a Hive table is extremely slow.

I have checked the sparkUI which shows all executors working but LTM the input is not read fast enough, it goes around 1MB/s.

The issue seems to be related to the number of columns, with 200 columns everything works fast.

After I have loaded the Hive table in a table with all 2k columns Hive SELECT and "CREATE TABLE AS SELECT..." statements work at normal speed. It's just the bridge between the spark dataframe and Hive.

Any hint on what the issue could be and how to solve it?

Comment: How many rows of data do you have?

Comment: I have tried with 25 and 5 million

Comment: why not just df.saveAsTable ? (idk what impact that might have on the column problem, but it might do something)

Comment: I have tried that as well. Anyway saveAsTable is deprecated.